# Dynamically prompt for string without knowing string size

Tags: c, dynamic, prompt, c-strings

In C, what is the best way of prompting and storing a string without wasted space if we cannot prompt for the string length. For example, normally I would do something like the following...

```
char fname[30];
char lname[30];

printf("Type first name:\n");
scanf("%s", fname);

printf("Type last name:\n");
scanf("%s", lname); 

printf("Your name is: %s %s\n", fname, lname);
```

However, I'm annoyed with the fact that I have to use more space than needed so I do not want to use `char fname[30]`, but instead dynamically allocate the size of the string. Any thoughts?

Comment: Use `malloc` to allocate a huge buffer. Other than your constant-storage spaces, `malloc`ed memory can be freed after use.

Comment: Asking user how long their name is wouldn't work so you're going to have to have an array big enough to hold the longest string allowed.  Note that I say allowed because you should limit the input to prevent buffer overflow.  Later, if you wish, you can resize the array to remove unused array elements.

Comment: If you have access to it, you could use `getline(NULL, ...` to allocate the buffer

Comment: What do you mean by "without wasted space"? Functions like `getline` will "waste" space at least in the sense of allocating more than absolutely necessary.

Comment: @mafso: that is precisely what the OP asks. Allocating a string in advance is tricky, because [how long can a name be](http://www.google.com/search?q=full+name+of+tuco)?

Comment: @Jongware: Yes, it's almost impossible to know in advance. The only way without wasting any space is to allocate byte-by-byte as needed. This is obviously not the answer, so I asked what's meant by "without wasted memory".

Comment: @mafso getline gives back space it doesn't need via realloc so, no, it doesn't waste. "This is obviously not the answer" -- why not? It's obvious to me that one can write a function that allocates bytes as needed. People who think this is unacceptably inefficient aren't thinking clearly ... the time is irrelevant and, besides, malloc can efficiently grow allocated chunks.

Comment: I updated the code in my answer to trim the unused memory before returning the collected input, as suggested by @FiddlingBits.

Comment: @JimBalter: This is at least an "intermediate" waste, I find the question is still a little unclear… For your second point (against my "obviously not the answer"): ACK.

Comment: @mafso An "intermediate waste" that doesn't last past the getline function is no waste at all; that sort of moving the goalposts is just a desperate attempt not to be wrong. And if you find the question unclear that's entirely your problem. But thanks for the ACK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a function that dynamically allocates memory for the input as the user types, using `getchar()` to read one character at a time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void* safeRealloc(void* ptr, size_t size) {
  void *newPtr = realloc(ptr, size);
  if (newPtr == NULL) { // if out of memory
    free(ptr); // the memory block at ptr is not deallocated by realloc
  }
  return newPtr;
}

char* allocFromStdin(void) {
  int size = 32; // initial str size to store input
  char* str = malloc(size*sizeof(char));
  if (str == NULL) {
    return NULL; // out of memory
  }
  char c = '\0';
  int i = 0;
  do {
    c = getchar();
    if (c == '\r' || c == '\n') {
        c = '\0'; // end str if user hits <enter>
    }
    if (i == size) {
        size *= 2; // duplicate str size
        str = safeRealloc(str, size*sizeof(char)); // and reallocate it
        if (str == NULL) {
          return NULL; // out of memory
        }
    }
    str[i++] = c;
  } while (c != '\0');
  str = safeRealloc(str, i); // trim memory to the str content size
  return str;
}

int main(void) {
  puts("Type first name:\n");
  char* fname = allocFromStdin();

  puts("Type last name:\n");
  char* lname = allocFromStdin();

  printf("Your name is: %s %s\n", fname, lname);

  free(fname); // free memory afterwards
  free(lname); // for both pointers
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should `realloc` at the end to remove all waste, right?

Comment: Yes, you should `free()` after using the data to remove the waste!

Comment: Make sure there is a terminating `0` at the end. I was thinking of this very same solution. Quite unexpectedly, it returns the correct string and length even if I used Backspace (on OSX Terminal). I would have guessed this needed special handling in the code.

Comment: @ericbn No, I mean `realloc` at the end of `allocFromStdin` to make the allocated buffer the perfect length to fit the name.

Comment: This actually has a memory leak because when realloc fails (returning NULL) it doesn't free the old the memory. Not a big deal since programs usually terminate when running out of memory, but worth pointing out. Also Fiddling Bits is correct, you should trim the size of the returned memory to the size of the content.

Answer (score 3):

From `man scanf`:

> • An optional 'm' character. This is used with string conversions (%s,
>   %c, %[), and relieves the caller of the need to allocate a
>   corresponding buffer to hold the input: instead, scanf() allocates a
>   buffer of sufficient size, and assigns the address of this buffer to
>   the corresponding pointer argument, which should be a pointer to a
>   char * variable (this variable does not need to be initialized before
>   the call). The caller should subsequently free(3) this buffer when it
>   is no longer required.

this however is a POSIX extension (as noted by fiddling_bits).

To be portable I think that in your usage case I would prepare a function like the following:

```
char *alloc_answer() {
  char buf[1000];
  fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin);
  size_t l = strlen(buf);
  if (buf[l-1]=='\n') buf[l]=0; // remove possible trailing '\n'
  return strdup(buf);
}
```

even if this solution will break lines longer than 1000 characters (but it prevents buffer overflow, at least).

A fully featured solution would need to read input in chunks and realloc the buffer on every chunk...

Comment: +1 Very clean solution. Suggestion: remove `'\n'` that `fgets` leaves in `buf`.

Comment: `fgets` reads at most one byte less than the second argument and still 0-terminates the buffer. `fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);` is fine.